# How to populate millions of Records in a SWT/Swing Table efficiently

Tags: java, algorithm, swing, swt

This is a general question but I have a particular scenario-
I am getting records through JNI layer from `<XYZ>` Hardware device, its give me millions/huge number of records and to handle all of them in SWT Table is like messing your mess in the wall, it just crashes.

> So for efficient programming , I worked with ScrollBar , I took the UI
>   size wrt to scroll bar and then that much particular data I populate,
>   then again when move the scrollbar , again next set of data , but I
>   realized its not at all an efficient way because on every movement of
>   scrollbar , I was calling the Hardware through JNI layer and that is
>   very expensive way

So Now I have a bit of time so thought of updating the logic.
Please provide me some efficient algorithm .

**There won't be any Paging Strategy , just a vertical ScrollBar till the last record**

*Million are just a figure , its not mandatory to have million records. I just want to know some efficient algorithm to populate large number of records*

Comment: Why would anyone want to have such a table with millions of records? You will not be able to scroll through it's content anyway, so what is the use case?

Comment: I am getting log traces from a Hardware devices , so those in N Numbers.... and please dont stick to the word Millions... its like how to populate it efficiently if bulk records are thre

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, one of the 'problems' of a `JTable` is that it loops over the whole model to calculate the size of the columns. So even with a scrollbar, it will loop over the whole model (and not only the visualized part) the first time it is painted.

The `JXTable` of SwingX allows to set a prototype value on your columns (`TableColumnExt#setPrototypeValue`) which avoids this loop. Setting this value can have a significant improvement of the table creation times.

Comment: I would hope that this could be solved using `JTable` as well, either by providing a `ColumnModel` or by having the model initially expose only a few rows, and add the other rows only after column widths have been calculated. Don't have any experience there, though.

Comment: `setAutoResizeMode(AUTO_RESIZE_OFF)` might be useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you use some kind of data store to represent your data efficiently. Depends on the data, but an array of custom objects might do. Then you wrap this into your own custom [TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) and let Swing take care of the rest. Undisplayed data should not require any resources at all.

Comment: if records are more then array or any available java collection wont able to handle , as those collections do have a certain limit to hold data

Comment: @bunta, if you have trouble to even keep the data in memory, than that problem is rather unrelated to how you present the data to the user. In that case, some [raw binary representation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) stored in [memory-mapped files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map%28java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long%29) might help. But a million objects should be far from the limits where such hacks would be neccessary.